# ZSH host name completion behaviour change?

Tags: zsh

I have been using ZSH to do host name completion, and want to change the default behaviour. When I have multiple hosts with similar names, the completion does stuff that I don't care for.  An example is best:

Let's say I have these hosts:

```
host01.stage.example.com
host02.stage.example.com
host01.prod.example.com
host02.prod.example.com
```

now, in my prompt, I will type:

```
$ ssh hos<tab>
```

zsh will show me:

```
$ ssh host..example.com
```

with the cursor right after "host" and shows me a menu with the host names in it.  I like the menu showing me hostnames, I just don't want it to complete everything. Weird things happen.  Most of the time I tab through and either have to delete host names or have extra stuff on the line i have to delete.

A preferred way would be to not complete the rest of the hostname.  something like:

```
$ ssh hos<tab>
```

zsh would hopefully show me:

```
$ ssh host
host01.stage.example.com  host01.prod.example.com
host02.stage.example.com  host02.prod.example.com
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

did you change anything in your .zshrc file ? Because when I do

```
ssh 127<tab>
```

it gives me correct suggestions... the cursor goes at the right place:

```
ssh 127.0.<cursor>.1
127.0.0.1 127.0.1.1
```

(the second line is the suggestions get)

Comment: PinkFloyd, this is exactly the behavior that the OP described that he/she wanted to get rid of.

Comment: @jayhendren not it's not